# Frustrating upgrade J2.5 to J3 not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a website with overt 25,000 article from 2.5 to Joomla 3 and I'm having all kind of problems.

First, I tried upgrading with the update button and that just crashed everything. Now after installing a new J2.5 installation, using the old database, installed j2xml to export all articles and categories but, the damn thing is not even displaying all articles, it just shows a blank page.

Is there a way to export the tables MANUALLY with mysqldump? I noticed J2.5 and J3 content table differs so, couldn't do it.

Can someone please guide me into the right track.

Thanks in advanced for your time.

Comment: I really hope you took a backup before the migration

Comment: Could you please describe more in detail what crashed? I did many updates from J2.5 to J3 and mostly the extensions that are not compatible with J3 (you didn't update theme yet i assume). Try to update the extension first.

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of SP Transfer.  You can migrate over the database table pretty easily that way.

https://www.kainotomo.com/products/sp-transfer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a new site. You can just update by following these steps - Video by Brian Teemann on [Siteground](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla-video/upgrade-introduction/)